# SAS: View to Table

Tags: view, sas, dataset

How to create table from view?

view named `A` -> table named `A`

I find only `proc sql` and `data set` statements, but is there any native function in sas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* create a table as a copy of data from view by SQL ... */

proc sql;
create table A_COPY as select * from A;
quit;

/* ... or by DATA step */
data A_COPY;
set A;
run;

/* Delete the view A 
  and rename the table to original view name */
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
delete A / mt=view;
change A_COPY = A / mt=data;
quit;
```

EDIT:

you can retrieve the code that created either a DATA step view or SQL view to LOG by "describing it":

```
data A /view=A;
    set sashelp.air;
run;

data view = A;
    describe;
run;



proc sql;
create view A as select * from sashelp.air;
describe view A;
quit;
```

Comment: hm.. good one, but is there any function to "**compile**" code that stored in view to generate table?

Comment: see my EDIT for retrieving the VIEW definition